# TimeStamp.valueOf() method

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, timestamp

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(116, 02, 12, 20, 45, 0, 0);
        Date d = new Date();
        d.setTime(ts.getTime());
        System.out.println(d);
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        //System.out.println(ts.getTime());
        System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(ts));
        System.out.println(Timestamp.valueOf(simpleDateFormat.format(ts)));

    }
```

In above code last two lines print different values. Current time zone is CST, I wanted to convert it into UTC. When I convert it Last two lines print different values by one hour i.e., last but one print 13 mar 2:45 am and last print 13 Mar 3:45 am. Why they are different and How can I correct it.

Comment: Are you aware that that `Timestamp` constructor is deprecated? And the the entire `Timestamp` class is outmoded along with `Date` and the troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`? Today you can pass an `Instant` or a `LocalDateTime` to your SQL database, so you need not use `Timestamp` any longer.

Comment: As Ole V.V. commented, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, and `java.sql.Timestamp` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Java 8

```
    Instant inst = LocalDateTime.of(2016, Month.MARCH, 12, 20, 45)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"))
            .toInstant();
    System.out.println(inst);
```

This prints

> 2016-03-13T02:45:00Z

Today you should not (normally) have a need for a `Timestamp` object. The `java.sql.Timestamp` class is long outdated. Once we used it for transferring timestamp values with nanosecond precision to and from SQL databases. Today we use the `Instant` class for this instead. `Instant` is one of the classes of `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API (sometimes we use `LocalDateTime` from the same API, it depends on your exact requirements and the datatype of your database column).

Neither a `Timestamp` nor an `Instant` have a time zone in them. Unlike `Timestamp` the `Instant` always prints in UTC (denoted by the `Z` at the end of the above output). As you can see, the above snippet has correctly converted your time of 20:45 CST to 02:45 the next day UTC.

If you do need a timestamp, typically for a legacy API that you cannot change or don’t want to change just now, conversion is easy:

```
    Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from(inst);
    System.out.println(ts);
```

> 2016-03-12 20:45:00.0

`Timestamp.toString` uses the JVM’s time zone setting for generating the string, so you recognize the time we started out from. So the `Timestamp` contains the correct point in time. There is no need to convert it in any way. If it gets inserted incorrectly into your database, the problem is with your JDBC driver, your database or somewhere else, and you should prefer to correct it there if you can.

### Java 6 and 7

Code very similar to the above will work in Java 7 if you add ThreeTen Backport to your project. This is the backport of the `java.time` classes to Java 6 and 7, and I include a link at the bottom (it’s ThreeTen for JSR-310, where the modern API was first described).

```
    Instant inst = LocalDateTime.of(2016, Month.MARCH, 12, 20, 45)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"))
            .toInstant();
    Timestamp ts = DateTimeUtils.toSqlTimestamp(inst);
```

You notice that the only difference from Java 8 is the way we convert the `Instant` to a `Timestamp`. The result is the same, of course.

I you don’t want a dependency on ThreeTen Backport, there are of course still ways to obtain a `Timestamp`. I wouldn’t use the deprecated constructor, as you do in your code, even though it works as long as no one tampers with your JVM’s time zone setting. If you know you want a `Timestamp` equal to 02:45 UTC, one option is

```
    Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2016-03-12 20:45:00");
```

It still depends on your JVM’s time zone setting, though.

### What went wrong in your code?

As mentioned a `Timestamp` hasn’t got a time zone in it, so converting a `Timestamp` to UTC does not make sense.

What happens in your code:

- The deprecated `Timestamp` constructor uses your JVM’s time zone setting (America/Chicago, I presume) for constructing a `Timestamp` corresponding 12 March 2016 at 8.45 PM in your time zone (the same point in time as 13 March 2:45 AM UTC).
- Your `SimpleDateFormat` correctly formats this into `2016-03-13 02:45:00` (UTC).
- `Timestamp.valueOf()` too uses America/Chicago time zone. However, on the night between 12 and 13 March summer time (daylight saving time) begins in this time zone. At 2 AM the clock is moved forward to 3. So there *is* no 2:45 this night. `Timestamp` picks 3:45 instead.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7.
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: Thanks for explaining Can it be solved i.e., Can I in anyway hold 2:45 UTC with a Java class.

Comment: Thanks @Ole V.V we are using Java 7 in our project. Can you help to convert timestamp of one zone to  any other way

Comment: I will be very happy if you could :).